# XML Commenting tips for C# programming

Tags: c#, documentation, documentation-generation, sandcastle, xml-comments

Good morning, afternoon, evening or night (depending on your timezone).

This is just a general question about XML commenting within C#. I have never been very big into commenting my programs, I've always been more of a verbose variable/property/method namer and letting the code speak for itself. I do write comments if I'm coding something that is fairly confusing, but for the most part I don't write alot of comments.

I was doing some reading about XML comments in .NET, Sandcastle, and the help file builder on codeplex and it has taken me down the path of wanting to document my code and generate some nice, helpful documentation for those who have to dig into my code when I'm no longer here.

My question is about standards and conventions. Is there a guide to "good" XML commenting? Should you comment EVERY variable and property? EVERY method? I'm just basically looking for tips on how to write good comments that will be compiled by sandcastle into good documentation so other programmers don't curse my name when they end up having to work on my code.

Thank you in advance for your advice and suggestions,
Scott Vercuski

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, we make sure that every public and protected method has XML comments.  It also will provide you with Intellisense, and not just end-user help documentation.  In the past, we also have included it on privately scoped declarations, but do not feel it is 100% required, as long as the methods are short and on-point.

Don't forget that there are tools to make you XML commenting tasks easier:

- [GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/) - Comment inheritance and templating add-in.
- [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB) - Edits the Sandcastle projects via a GUI, can be run from a command line (for build automation), and can edit MAML for help topics not derived from code. (The 1.8.0.0 alpha version is very stable and very improved.  Have been using it for about a month now, over 1.7.0.0)

Answer (score 6):

Comments are very often outdated. This always has been a problem. My rule of thumb : the more you need to work to update a comment, the faster that comment will be obsolete.

XML Comments are great for API development. They works pretty well with Intellisens and they can have you generate an HTML help document in no time.

But this is not free: maintaining them will be hard (look at any non-trivial example, you will understand what I mean), so they will tend to be outdated very fast. As a result, **reviewing XML Comments should be added to your code review as a mandatory check** and this check should be performed every time a file is updated.

Well, since it is expensive to maintain, since a lot of non private symbols (in non-API development) are used only by 1 or 2 classes, and since these symboles are often self-explanatory, I would never enforce a rule saying that every non-private symbol should be XML commented. **This would be overkill and conterproductive**. What you will get is what I saw at a lot of places : nearly empty XML Comments adding nothing to the symbole name. And code that is just a little less readable...

I think that the **very, very** important guide line about comments in normal (non-API) code should not be about **HOW they should be written** but about **WHAT they should contain**. A lot of developers still don't know **what** to write. A description of what should be commented, with examples, would do better for your code than just a plain : "Do use XML Comments on every non-private symbole.".

Answer (score 3):

I document public classes and the Public/Protected Members of those classes.

I don't document private or internal members or internal classes.  Hence variables (I think you mean fields) because they are private.

The objective is to create some documentation for a developer who does not have ready access to the source code.

Endeavour to place some examples where usage is not obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I very rarely comment on method variables, and equally rarely fields (since they are usually covered by a property, or simply don't exist if using auto-implemented properties).

Generally I try hard to add meaningful comments to all public/protected members, which is handy, since if you turn on the xml comments during build, you get automatic warnings for missing comments. Depending on the complexity, I might not fill out every detail - i.e. if it is 100% obvious what every parameter *has* to do (i.e. there is no special logic, and there is only 1 logical way of interpreting the variables), then I *might* get lazy and not add comments about the parameters.

But I certainly try to describe what methods, types, properties, etc represent/do.

Answer (score 0):

We document the public methods/properties/etc on our libraries. As part of the build process we use NDoc to create an MSDN-like web reference. It's been very helpful for quick reference and lookup.

It's also great for Intellisense, especially with new team members or, like you said, when the original author is gone.

I agree that code, in general, should be self-explanatory. The XML documention, to me, is more about reference and lookup when you don't have the source open.

Answer (score 0):

Personally my opinion is to avoid commenting. Commenting is dangerous. Because in industry we always update code(because business & requirements are always changing), but vary rarely we update our comments. This may misguide the programmers.

Comment: It might appear to be more work but comments are there to improve code understanding, should be part of your job to update the code, and update the comments.